# AFNetworking 2 - post request- add simple text to body

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

This is my first post in here and is not a repost, I have searched a lot in Stack Overflow for the answer, but without luck... The problem that I'm having is an intermittent error: "request body stream exhausted" with the code:-1021, I'm using AFNetworking 2.

This is what I use to create a RequestOperationManager:

```
 - (AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *)createDefaultManager {

     AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *postRequest = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myURL"]];
     postRequest.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
     postRequest.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];
     [postRequest.requestSerializer setValue:@"Keep-Alive" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
     [postRequest.requestSerializer setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
     [postRequest.requestSerializer setValue:@"en-US" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Language"];

     return postRequest;
 }
```

Here is my post method:

```
 - (void)postRequest:(AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *)request withURL:(NSString *)url withBody:(NSString *)body {

    [request POST:url parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
    {
       [formData throttleBandwidthWithPacketSize:kAFUploadStream3GSuggestedPacketSize
                                                  delay:kAFUploadStream3GSuggestedDelay];

       NSMutableDictionary *mutableHeaders = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
       [mutableHeaders setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"text/xml"] forKey:@"Content-Type"];
       [mutableHeaders setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"any-value"] forKey:@"User-Agent"];
       [formData appendPartWithHeaders:mutableHeaders body:[NSData dataWithBytes:[body UTF8String] length:[body length]]];

     } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [self connectionSuccess:operation withResponse:responseObject];
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [self connectionFailed:operation withError:error];
        NSLog(@"Here's the request: %@", operation.request.HTTPBody);
 }];
}
```

I don't know what is wrong in what I'm doing. That should work all the time.

Thanks,
JJ

Comment: The docs say that you should be sending the request unthrottled first, and then throttle it if you receive the error. Have you tried doing that, rather than just throttling all requests? http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Protocols/AFMultipartFormData.html#//api/name/throttleBandwidthWithPacketSize:delay:

Comment: Can you post your solution? Please. - thanks